# Handling empty or null values In SELECT statement using case

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I'm trying to use Case Statement for the following

```
 SELECT .. to_number(nvl(il.var1,0)) * to_number(nvl(il.var2,0)) * to_number(nvl(il.var3,0))/1000000 AS calculated_value,
```

Sometimes, either var1 or var2 or var3 will have alphabets inside(dirty data) in which my query will return an error.

How do I structure my query with case statement in which if the result of the equation does not return me valid numeric or if var1 | var2| var3 is not integer, set calculated_value as "0" or "Empty" for that row only?

Comment: Dirty data? So why are these columns strings in the first place? With an appropriate column data type there would be no problem at all.

Comment: If you are on Oracle 12.2 or can upgrade to it, you can use the `default n on conversion error` parameter to [`to_number`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_NUMBER.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check whether those VARx really are numbers. For example:

```
from ...
where regexp_like(il.var1, '^\d+$')
  and regexp_like(il.var2, '^\d+$')
  and regexp_like(il.var3, '^\d+$')
```

[EDIT] Aha, you'd still want to get some result.

Then you'd use something like this: if VARx isn't a number, use "0" (zero) and the final result will be 0.

```
select case when not regexp_like(il.var1, '^\d+$') then 0
            else il.var1
       end
       *
       case when not regexp_like(il.var2, '^\d+$') then 0
            else il.var2
       end
       as result
from ...
```

Comment: Sorry, what is the purpose of the *, im getting syntax errors.

Comment: Multiplying, as that's what I saw you doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT 
  CASE WHEN ((REGEXP_LIKE (il.var1,'^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$')
              OR  (REGEXP_LIKE (il.var2,'^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$') 
              OR (REGEXP_LIKE (il.var3,'^-?\d+ (\.\d+)?$'))
       THEN 0
  ELSE
     to_number(nvl(il.var1,0)) * to_number(nvl(il.var2,0)) * to_number(nvl(il.var3,0))/1000000 AS calculated_value
```

Comment: Hm, that should be vice versa, shouldn't it? As you put it, the result will be 0 if VARx **are** numbers.

Comment: ^ Yes, my fields are now all 0